KDB Matrix dot product (mmu) for 2*3, 3*2 length error
why mmu function is throwing length error for 2 by 3, 3 by 2 matrix in KDB.
Could you please share me the links for matrix examples in KDB
    q)x:2 3#1+til 6
    q)y:3 2#7+til 6
    q)x
    1 2 3
    4 5 6
    q)y
    7  8
    9  10
    11 12
    q)x mmu y
    'length
      [0]  x mmu y
             ^

//Multiplication also not working  here
q)x * y
'length
  [0]  x * y
         ^

Result I expect and matrix rules I reffered.



mmu operates on float matrices only:
q)x:2 3#9h$1+til 6
q)y:3 2#9h$7+til 6
q)x mmu y
58  64
139 154

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/mmu/
Without mmu:
q)mmu2:{sum each'x*/:\:flip y}
q)x:2 3#1+til 6
q)y:3 2#7+til 6
q)mmu2[x;y]
58  64
139 154

But is much slower than the built-in.

Hi Cillian, Thank you for prompt response. I referred this example as well but I am looking for reason why dot matrix is not working in KDB. You mean to say there is no way to do dot matrix on numbers in KDB?,  I do not agree on this.

Sure you can. But you have to do it yourself, I've updated the answer

So Data type is mandatory for dot matrix or multiplication in KDB. For list data type will not allow multiplication, is my understanding correct.

Float is mandatory for mmu yes. You can multiply a list of longs by an atom or by another list of conforming length. In your example, x and y have different counts so you see a length error. e.g. 2*2 3#1+til 6 works, as does 2 4*2 3#1+til 6. The first multiplies by an atom, the second by a list of conforming length
